# Calculating RSI for Multiple Dates and Tickers in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, calc

I can calculate RSI for a specific end date:

```
DECLARE @StartingDate smalldatetime
    DECLARE @EndingDate smalldatetime
    DECLARE @StockID char(15)
    DECLARE @DAYS INT
    DECLARE @AG FLOAT
    DECLARE @AL FLOAT
    DECLARE @RS FLOAT

    SET @StartingDate = '20180301'
    SET @EndingDate = '20180403'
    SET @StockID = 'ACE'
    SET @DAYS = 14

    SET @AG =(
                SELECT SUM([px_close]-[px_open]) 
                FROM [dbo].[daily_data]
                WHERE [Ticker] = @STOCKID
                AND ([Date] BETWEEN @StartingDate AND @EndingDate) 
                AND ([px_close]-[px_open])>0)/@DAYS

    SET @AL =(
                SELECT SUM([px_close]-[px_open])
                FROM [dbo].[daily_data]
                WHERE [Ticker] = @STOCKID 
                AND ([Date] BETWEEN @StartingDate AND @EndingDate) 
                AND ([px_close]-[px_open])<0)/@DAYS
    SET @RS = @AG/ABS(@AL)
    SELECT @StockID AS Ticker, @EndingDate AS Date, 100 - (100/(1+@RS)) RSI
```

Here's my output:

```
Ticker  Date        RSI
ACE    2018-04-03   48.7307
```

How can I calculate RSI for multiple dates and multiple tickers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set all of these to variables. You can just add the date and ticker to the group by and avoid the redundant subqueries... something like:

```
SELECT 
    [Ticker]
    ,[Date]
    ,AG = SUM(case when (isnull([px_close],0)-isnull([px_open],0))>0 then (isnull([px_close],0)-isnull([px_open],0)) end) / @days
    ,AL = SUM(case when (isnull([px_close],0)-isnull([px_open],0))<0 then (isnull([px_close],0)-isnull([px_open],0)) end) / @days
    ,RS = (SUM(case when (isnull([px_close],0)-isnull([px_open],0))>0 then (isnull([px_close],0)-isnull([px_open],0)) end) / @days) /  ABS(SUM(case when (isnull([px_close],0)-isnull([px_open],0))<0 then (isnull([px_close],0)-isnull([px_open],0)) end) / @days)
    ,RSI = 100 - (100/(1+(SUM(case when (isnull([px_close],0)-isnull([px_open],0))>0 then (isnull([px_close],0)-isnull([px_open],0)) end) / @days) /  ABS(SUM( case when (isnull([px_close],0)-isnull([px_open],0))<0 then (isnull([px_close],0)-isnull([px_open],0)) end) / @days)))
FROM 
    [dbo].[daily_data]
WHERE 
    [Ticker] = @STOCKID
    AND ([Date] BETWEEN @StartingDate AND @EndingDate) 
group by
    [Ticker],[Date]
```

Remove `[Ticker] = @STOCKID` from the where clause to return all Tickers

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: ,AG = SUM( case when ([px_close]-[px_open])>0) then [px_close]-[px_open] end ) / @days

Comment: Am I missing a left paren?

Comment: I now get NULLS for RS and RSI

Comment: That's because there are null values in [px_close] or [px_open]. I made a change. Sorry, kind of hard to follow without sample data and expected output.

Comment: Thanks.  Working through some issues.  Just realized the original code was not confined to the 14day lookback

Comment: Issues with your data or with my hands hurt? Did it work as you wanted?

Comment: Still getting NULLS for RS and RSI.  But I want to walk thru my original code first and then I'll post sample data and expected output

Comment: That’s fair. I’d close this one and open a new one or you may not get many views